# FormatMethod: how to forward their arguments to another format method?

Tags: java, checker-framework

I don't understand why I get an error related to `@FormatMethod`.

Here's a very simple example, that fails:

```
import org.checkerframework.checker.formatter.qual.FormatMethod;
import java.util.Locale;

public class FormatExample {

    public void example() {
        String ex1 = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s %d", "cost", 12);
        log("%d", 0);
    }

    @FormatMethod
    static void log(String format, Object... args) {
        String ex1 = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, format, args);
        // The line above causes the error (see below)
    }
}
```

It fails with the following error-message:

```
FormatExample.java:13: error: 
    [format.string.invalid] invalid format string (is a @Format annotation missing?)
                String ex1 = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, format, args);
```

What am I missing?
I am using version: `javac 1.8.0-jsr308-2.1.14`

What I try to do is very similar to the example in the [docs: 10.5 @FormatMethod](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#formatter-FormatMethod):

> Your project may contain methods that forward their arguments to a
>   format method. Consider for example the following log method:
>
> ```
> @FormatMethod
> void log(String format, Object... args) {
>     if (enabled) {
>         logfile.print(indent_str);
>         logfile.printf(format , args);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> You should annotate such a method with the @FormatMethod annotation.
>   This instructs the Format String Checker to check every invocation of
>   the method. This check is analogous to the check done on every
>   invocation of built-in format methods like String.format.

**Hint**:
you can easily reproduce the issue in the [Checker Framework Live Demo](http://eisop.uwaterloo.ca/live).

- don't forget to change `Choose a type system:` to `Format String Checker`
- keep in mind that the online-tool uses an older version of the Checker Framework (`2.1.10` @ 08.09.2017)

Answer (score 1):

The `@FormatMethod` annotation was working as documented, but not as you wanted -- and your interpretation was a reasonable one.

The [manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#formatter-FormatMethod) and the [`@FormatMethod` documentation](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/formatter/qual/FormatMethod.html) say that `@FormatMethod` causes calls to the annotated method to be checked, but they make no promises about calls within the annotated method.

However, this [bug](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/issues/1507) has been recently [fixed](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/commit/d5a1864179cc09dc566ff93f8189e38b1bc2789e).  You can [build the Checker Framework from source](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#build-source) or wait for the next release.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - looking forward to the next release.  
But I still don't understand why the `log()` example in chapter 10.5 (see the quote in my answer) would work. It also uses `logfile.printf()` in the method body.  
Is there maybe some annotation on `logfile.printf()` to suppress the error?

Comment: I suspect the chapter 10.5 example didn't work before.  (The Checker Framework contained no such test case.)  It does work now.